# Can't compile NPOI project

Tags: c#, .net, xls, npoi

I'd like to use the NPOI dll in my project, so I downloaded the source code from [https://github.com/tonyqus/npoi] as there was no binary download.

I opened this solution \solution\visualstudio\NPOI.sln and compiled it,

However I get the following errors:

[image: error]

I compiled earlier releases and got the same error. Am I missing something?

Comment: Show your errors as a text. Can we see the actual code that generates these error messages? Looks like you need to put related `using` directive and/or related assembly. And define your `Complex` in related context.

Comment: The binaries are [hosted on CodePlex](https://npoi.codeplex.com/releases), it seems up to date (current version 2.1.3.1) with the github repo. I suggest you use these instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very strange, but it looks like three source code files are present in archive, but not included in the project.

So open NPOI.sln solution in Visual Studio, then go to `SS -> Formula` folder in Solution Explorer. Rightclick on `Functions` folder, select `Add` -> `existed item` in context menu, and then add these files:

- main/SS/Formula/Functions/Code.cs
- main/SS/Formula/Functions/Complex.cs
- main/SS/Formula/Functions/Rept.cs

**Update**: I've created pull request to tonyqus/npoi GitHub repository having these files added back to project. Request has been accepted now, so you can simply download sources from GitHub again - it will be compiled.